# Mysql update not changing values in data table? Query not made?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to mysql and am attempting to replace one value in a column with another. Right now I have 2 inputs and can echo the text value of these inputs here as well as the username of the person logged in:

```
<?php

session_start();
include("../php/Session.class.php");
$sess = new Session();
$sess->Init();
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE["session"]); 
if($cookie) 
{
$cookie = $_COOKIE["session"];
$account = $sess->Verify($cookie);
}

$pass1=$_POST['passwordText']; //name of input
    echo $pass1;    

$pass=$_POST['oldPass']; //name of input
    echo $pass;
echo $account['username'];
```

I then connect to my database and am trying to set the previous password to the value of `$pass1` where the user's username is located.

```
$dbh = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");
    $checkforpass = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username='".$account['username']."'";

$checkforpass = $dbh->query($checkforpass); //make query
$checkforpass = $checkforpass->fetch_assoc(); //prepare sql
$checkforpass = $checkforpass['password'];

echo $checkforpass;

if($checkforpass==$pass)
{
    echo 'they got the password!';

    $change = "UPDATE accounts SET password=".$pass1." WHERE username='".$account['username']."'";
    //$change = $dbh->query($change);
    $dbh->query($change); //make query
        $dbh->close();

    //change password

}
```

I get no errors but when checking my local data base the value of password stays the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You may want to name your variables better and avoid using the same variable to unrelated values to improve readability. I also suggest looking up sql injection while investigating database security standards and the use of parameterised queries

Answer (score 0):

I think its not getting inserted/updated because you are not using single quotes around `varchar` in the query.

Your query should be :

```
$change = "UPDATE accounts SET password='".$pass1."' WHERE username='".$account['username']."'";
```

OR

```
$change = "UPDATE accounts SET password='$pass1' WHERE username='".$account['username']."'";
```